# Best way to import time series from CSV and plot a graph using Python

Tags: python, perl

One task I have to do many times is to read a CSV file with some time series data and then plot a graph showing it all.

I have to import the data from a CSV file. It may not be sorted, it may have gaps and each series can start and end in different dates. For example:

```
Employee;Year;Salary
Mark;2014;29000
Paul;2013;33000
Paul;2014;34000
Mark;2011;20000
Mark;2012;24000
Mark;2015;30000
```

And I want to put it all in a graph showing each time series (two lines where X-axis will be the date and Y-axis the salary of the employee). It is crucial to take into account any existing gaps in data.

Ok, so I started to learn programming with Perl. And my first approach to the problem was:

First, import the data from the CSV and store it into a hash, like this:

```
$imported_data->{$employee}{$year} = $salary;
```

After importing the data, I generate a sorted series of dates without gaps using a loop and the DateTime module. It will result in an array like this:

```
[ 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 ]
```

Then, I generate the arrays of salary data for each employee. I use the array of dates to make a loop finding the salary for each date and returning an undef if the data is missing:

```
for my $date (@dates) {
    $salary = $imported_data->{$employee}{$year};
    if ( defined $salary ) {
        push @salary_array, $salary;
    } else {
        push @salary_array, undef;
    }
}
```

This will result in the following arrays (one for each employee):

```
[ 20000, 24000, undef, 29000, 30000 ]
[ undef, undef, 33000, 34000, undef ]
```

And now I can plot the data pairing the array of dates (X values) with each array of salaries (Y values), resulting in an XY graph with two series. The data is now sorted and the gaps will be shown properly.

Ok, I don't know if this is the best way (probably not...), but it worked fine.

However, now I am starting to use Phyton and I want to rethink this way of doing the task. As you can see, in Perl I have used a hash of hashes to store the imported data. I don't know if Phyton's dictionaries can do this and if it is easy to manage.

So I am open to ideas from more experienced programmers. How would you do it? Is there any useful module for this kind of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are new at python, I recommend that you take a look at `numpy` and `pandas` for general math and data manipulation, and at `matplotlib` for plotting.

As for this problem, a possible solution is this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = [["Mark", 2014, 29000],
        ["Paul", 2013, 33000],
        ["Paul", 2014, 34000],
        ["Mark", 2011, 20000],
        ["Mark", 2012, 24000],
        ["Mark", 2015, 30000]]

data_csv = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Employee", "Year", "Salary"])


data_dict = defaultdict(list)

for row in data_csv.values:
        data_dict[row[0]].append(row[1:])


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()


for name in data_dict.keys():
        data_dict[name] = np.concatenate(data_dict[name]).reshape(-1, 2)
        ax.scatter(data_dict[name][:,0], data_dict[name][:,1], label=name)

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

In the first lines I create a dummy csv file with `pandas`, while in your case you will load it with `pd.read_csv`.

The core is the `defaultdict`: since a priori the number of employees is not known, the values of the dictionaries are initialized as lists. Then I go over every row in the csv and for every name (a key in the dict) I append to the list the year and salary. At that point it is just a matter of reshaping everything in a 2d array with `numpy` and plot the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example, using `numpy`, `defaultdict`, `csv.reader()`, and classes:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
    raw_data = FileReader(fn='salary.csv')
    data = ProcessData(raw_data)
    Plotter(data)

class ProcessData:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.t = sorted(data.years, key=int)
        self.names = sorted(list(data.salary.keys()))
        self.salary = dict()
        self.create_salary_data()

    def create_salary_data(self):
        for name in self.names:
            s = []
            for year in self.t:
                if year in self.data.salary[name]:
                    s.append(self.data.salary[name][year])
                else:
                    s.append(None)
            self.salary[name] = s

class FileReader:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if not 'fn' in kwargs:
            raise Exception('No file name given')
        self.fn = kwargs['fn']
        self.salary = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(float))
        self.years = set()
        self.read_file()

    def read_file(self):
        with open('salary.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
            header = next(reader)
            for row in reader:
                if len(row)==0:
                    continue
                if len(row) != 3:
                    raise Exception('Bad row length in csv file')
                name, year, salary = row
                self.salary[name][year] = salary
                self.years.add(year)

class Plotter:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        t = data.t
        names = sorted(list(data.salary.keys()))
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        for name in names:
            temp = data.salary[name]
            s = list(map(lambda ss: np.nan if ss is None else float(ss), temp))
            ax.plot(t, s, label=name)

        ax.set(xlabel='Date (year)', ylabel='Salary (\$\$)',
           title='Employee salary')
        ax.grid()
        ax.legend(loc='upper right')
        plt.show()

main()
```